# Subscribe to events within a WCF service

Tags: wcf, event-handling, delegates

I have a need to do some real-time reporting on the functionality of a WCF service.  The service is self-hosted in a windows app, and my requirement is to report "live" to the host app when certain methods are called by the client.

My initial thought on the task was to publish a "NotifyNow" event in the service code, and subscribe to the event in my calling app, but this doesn't seem to be possible.  Within my service code (implementation, not the interface) I have tried adding the following

```
public delegate void MessageEventHandler(string message);
public event MessageEventHandler outputMessage;

void SendMessage(string message)
{
    if (null != outputMessage)
    {
        outputMessage(message);
    }
}
```

and call the SendMessage method whenever I need to notify the host app of some action.  (This is based on what I remember of this kind of inter-form communication in a winforms app, and my memory may have let me down here...)

When I try to hook up the event handler in my host, though, I can't seem to figure out how to attach to the events...  My hosting code is (in a nutshell)

```
service = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
service.outputMessage += new MyService.MessageEventHandler(frm2_outputMessage);
  // the above line does not work!
service.Open();
```

(wrapped in a try/catch).

Can anyone help, either by telling me how to get this approach to work or by pointing me at a better way.

TIA

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did some more research this morning, and turned up a much simpler solution than has been outlined already.  The main source of information was [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2619300/Events-from-ServiceHost-instance.aspx), but it is summarised here.

1) in the service class, add the following (or similar) code..

```
public static event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> CustomEvent;

public void SendData(int value) 
{       
    if (CustomEvent != null)
        CustomEvent(null, new CustomEventArgs());
}
```

The important bit is to make the event static, otherwise you'll have no chance of catching it.

2) Define a CustomEventArgs class, for example...

```
public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Message;
    public string CallingMethod;                        
}
```

3) Add calling code in each method of the service in which you have an interest...

```
public string MyServiceMethod()
{
    SendData(6);
}
```

4) Instantiate the ServiceHost as normal, and hook into the event.

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
Service1.CustomEvent += new EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>(Service1_CustomEvent);
host.Open();
```

5) Handle the event messages that bubble up to the host from there.

Comment: CustomEvent does not show up under Service1 for me.  Does this work with WCF 4.5?

Answer (score 11):

The service variable is an instance of ServiceHost not your service implementation. Try something like:

```
MyService myService = new MyService();
myService.outputMessage += new MyService.MessageEventHandler(frm2_outputMessage);
host = new ServiceHost(myService);
```

Comment: Upvoted, although I didn't go down this route - I had some issues this afternoon that meant I couldn't spend the required time on it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be instantiating a default `ServiceHost` class:

```
service = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
              ***********
service.outputMessage += new MyService.MessageEventHandler(frm2_outputMessage);
  // the above line does not work!
```

and I highly doubt that would have a "outputMessage" property for an event handler.

Shouldn't you be instantiating your own custom service host, something like this:

```
class MyCustomServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
  ...... your custom stuff here ......
}

service = new MyCustomServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
              *******************
service.outputMessage += new MyService.MessageEventHandler(frm2_outputMessage);
```

??

Marc

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but I have to confess to not really knowing how I would go about it...  I'm with you all the way until ...your custom stuff here... :(  I suspect the issue I'm going to face is still around actually hooking into the main event handling code in the service

Comment: After getting home and turning my mind off for a while, I see exactly what you are saying - I'm looking at the ServiceHost, not the instance of the service...  I need to look at it again tomorrow and figure out what I need to code in the custom ServiceHost to pass the event through.  Thanks